# Trying to write a mysql Dockerfile. What is wrong with my Dockerfile?

Tags: mysql, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a mysql container running on rockylinux (as a replacement for centos8).

My problem is that the container runs and then immediately shuts down.

It is successfully building, just not able to persist.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rockylinux/rockylinux

RUN dnf -y install mysql-server

EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT [ "mysqld" ]
```

Build command used: `docker build -t blah/dbimage .`

Run command used: `docker run -d --name dbcontainer -p 3306:3306 blah/dbimage`

Comment: Any output on the console? A docker container typically shuts down when the process defined by ENTRYPOINT or CMD ends. And any particular reason why you don't use an offical mysql container as base for your project?

Comment: The only output is the container id after docker run, and after docker run it outputs the container name. Do you happen to know what ENTRYPOINT or CMD I should be using in instead in order to have it stick around?

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t running? Try running `docker ps`. Try connecting to mysql.

Comment: `docker ps` shows no running containers. But if I run `docker ps -a` I can see that the container exists, it's just not currently running